# How to add a callback to ajaxSetup() in jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap button that, when clicked displays 'loading'. When the AJAX request is completed, the button is reset to its normal state. All works fine with the below code:

```
function doThis() {

    var btn = $(this);
    btn.button('loading');

    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(data) {
            if(data!=null && data.status==='success') {
                btn.button('reset');
            }
            else {
                btn.button('reset');
            }
        }
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            btn.button('reset');
        }
    });
};
```

When I move parts of my error handling away from that function (because I don't want to repeat the error handling for every `$.ajax` call), `btn` is out of scope and cannot be reset.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        ...//lot of other code
        btn.button('reset');//doesn't work
    }
})
```

How can I provide `ajaxSetup()` with a callback?

Comment: why do you want to move it out... here the button logic is local to the method which is doing the ajax call so the reset of the button also should be local

Comment: @ArunPJohny - I think the problem is that the `btn` variable is scoped to the `doThis()` function and they can't reach it from the `AjaxSetup()` error handler.  The question seems misworded in relation to the actual problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes.. that is the problem.. but since the change in the button is done locally in the `doThis` function... moving the reset option to a global handler does not make much sense I think... so it will be better to do it in the `doThis` handler itself...

Comment: @ArunPJohny- I agree.  It could probably go in a `complete` handler inside of `doThis()`.

Comment: The error function defined in ajaxSetup covers more than just resetting the button. It has a lot of code parsing error codes and such, which I don't want to duplicate for every $.ajax() call.

Comment: @bart - so leave that stuff in `ajaxSetup()` and put the `btn` handling where it can access the variable.

Comment: @jfriend00 The button needs to reset on error. There is no other place to capture that event. If I set $.ajax{error: function(){...}} then it overrides $ajaxSetup().

Comment: You can use the `complete: function() {...}` option for `$.ajax()` to capture all possible ways the ajax function finishes (error and success) and then you can put all your reset code in one place and in scope of `btn`.

Comment: @jfriend00 I think that's the solution, thanks!

Comment: @bart you can also use the always handler to do the same.... see below answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to reset the button in case of success/failure so use .always() handler

```
function doThis() {

    var btn = $(this);
    btn.button('loading');

    $.ajax({
        //...
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != null && data.status === 'success') {
                //do stuff in case of success
            }
        }
    }).always(function () {
        btn.button('reset');
    });
};
```

Also for global ajax error handling use http://api.jquery.com/ajaxerror/ instead of setting `error` handler using `ajaxSetup`

Comment: This answer, alongside the 'complete' event answer by @jfriend00 seem the solution!

Comment: Can you explain why ajaxError() is preferred over ajaxSetup()?

Comment: @bart because when you use ajaxSetup and error handler.. as you did some where an ajax request can override it....

Comment: @bart but again it depends on your use case... if you have a default error handler which you want... but also want to allow each ajax request to override it if they wish then you can use ajaxSetup...

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `context` of `$.ajaxSetup()` to `btn` , a defined element , object

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  context: btn || $("button"), // set `this` within `success` , `error`
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // `this` : `btn || $("button")`
        // do stuff with `this`
        this.button('reset');
    }
})
```

Comment: I don't think this covers the issue the OP is having based on their comments.

Comment: @jfriend00 _"I don't think this covers the issue the OP is having based on their comments."_ Can describe why ? See OP at _"btn is out of scope and cannot be reset."_ Setting `context` within `$.ajaxSetup()` to a defined object should set `this` to the defined object within `success` , `error` callbacks

Answer (score 0):

If your `btn` is always the same, try declaring it outside the `doThis` function:

```
var btn = $('#btnId'); // declare variables outside

$.ajaxSetup({
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    btn.button('reset');
  }
});

function doThis() {
  $.ajax(...);
}
```

If your `btn` can be different on each `doThis` call, you should use a generator function:

```
function generateErrorHandler(btn) {
  return function() {
    btn.button('reset');
  };
}

function doThis() {
  var btn = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    ...
    error: generateHandler(btn)
  });
}
```